# Express Handlebars directory is not rendering result of views\home.handlebars . Asking for \views\layouts\main.handlebars'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, viewengine

I am trying to learn something new view engine but when I was reading the documentation on npm express-handlebars it showed directory structure like this :

.
├── app.js
└── views
├── home.handlebars
└── layouts
└── main.handlebars

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgtIo.png)

2 directories, 3 files

but when I am trying to implement it according to this its not working server is giving me an error :

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\code\views\layouts\main.handlebars'

```
const app = express();
const { engine } = require("express-handlebars")

app.engine("handlebars", engine(//I know I can change thing from here));
app.set("view engine","handlebars")

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("home");
})

app.listen(8080)
```

Comment: Please provide an error your getting

Comment: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\code\views\layouts\main.handlebars'

Comment: Why is it not showing the views folder home.handlebars file and asking for \views\layouts\main.handlebars file